# Can I delegate Google Apps email to Gmail account in a different domain?

Tags: google-workspace

I want to delegate my Google Apps email to someone else's Gmail.

I toggled the delegation flag in the Admin Console.

I then clicked on *Grant access to your account* in my Settings and entered their email, but got the following error:

> Error: You can only grant access to Google accounts in the same Google Apps organization.

Is it possible to delegate to domains outside of my organization? (I read somewhere about doing a MX verification, but we've already done that.)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, as the error message states.

The best you can do is to create a temporary account within your domain for the person you're trying to delegate to.

This account could be set up to forward all mail and give access to calendars to the Gmail account.